# PHP Unit test case for public static function in rest plugin

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, drupal-9

I am trying to write a unit test case for rest api in Drupal 9. To start with for the following code

```
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
        return new static(
                $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $container->getParameter('serializer.formats'), $container->get('logger.factory')->get('plusapi'), $container->get('current_user')
        );
    }
```

I have written following code

```
 public function testCreate() {

    $container = new ContainerBuilder();
    $logger = $this->getMockBuilder('LoggerInterface')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
    $accountproxy = $this->getMockBuilder(AccountProxyInterface::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
    //Set container parameters.
    $container->set('current_user', $accountproxy);
    $container->set('logger.factory', $logger);
    \Drupal::setContainer($container);
    $container->set('serializer.formats', $this->serializer_formats);
    $createnewsc_object = csCreateNews::create($container, $this->configuration,$this->pluginId, $this->pluginDefinition);
      
    $this->assertTrue(TRUE);
  }
```

But it gives the following error

**Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "serializer.formats".
**

I tried to set serializer.formats in container but its not working. Any suggestions?